# Shifting rows to previous observations

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please explain why this function doesn't work?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.apply(lambda row: row.shift(-1)[['col1']], axis=1)enter code here
```

It should return

> [2  3  4  5  NaN]

But it returns everything with `NaN`. I don't want to create a new column with previous observations and process through it. I want to learn how do everything inside a lambda.

Thank you very much : )

Answer (score 0):

When called with `axis=1`, `pd.apply` function will call your function with a different row every time. In this case, your lambda function will be called with a series containing 1 element (since every row contains 1 element). You can see it if you replace your lambda with `lambda row: print(row)`

Calling shift on a series with 1 element will always result in NaN, since there are no other values.